# PHP MVC controllers issue

Tags: php, model-view-controller, symfony1

I'm two days with an issue and I can not find the solution,

I have 3 modules Groups, Events and Pages

Events can be in groups and pages, then I want to access it this way:

```
/groups/{id}/events/{id}
/page/{id}/events/{id}
```

I have 3 controllers: `GroupController`, `EventController` and `PageController`

The events use the same model. But depending on whether they belong to a group or page event controller has a method that changes. I decided to create two controllers as

```
GroupEventController extends EventController
PageEventController  extends EventController
```

In the case of a `GroupEventController`, I also need `GroupController` data.

How do you do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "I also need GroupController data". The controllers don't have data, they just have methods. The data is in the model layer, which you can access from any controller.

Comment: sorry,i wanted to say methods.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about dual inheritance. PHP does not support this, however there are ways around it. In your case, you can have the inheritance chain. Route everything through the Group or Page controllers. These can extend the GroupEventController and PageEventController respectively. And both of those can extend the Event controller.

Comment: then, do i have route directly /groups/id/events/id to --> GroupEventController ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. However, this is the second question about this that I've answered. I suspect the issue is you don't know how to ask the question you really want to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You must route `/groups/:id/events/:event_id` to `GroupEventController` to a method :

Controller:

```
public function executeGroupData(sfWebRequest $request){
//Logic
}
```

Routing(routing.yml):

```
groupData:
  url: /group/:id/events/:event_id
  param: { module: groups, action: groupData }
```